# Setting the number of digits to a given value

Tags: r

Is there a way that one can set the number of digits of a full data frame to 2? Case in point, how would you set the number of digits to 2 for the following data using R?

```
 Distance Age Height Coning
1      21.4  18    3.3    Yes
2      13.9  17    3.4    Yes
3      23.9  16    2.9    Yes
4       8.7  18    3.6     No
5     241.8   6    0.7     No
6      44.5  17    1.3    Yes
7      30.0  15    2.5    Yes
8      32.3  16    1.8    Yes
9      31.4  17    5.0     No
10     32.8  13    1.6     No
11     53.3  12    2.0     No
12     54.3   6    0.9     No
13     96.3  11    2.6     No
14    133.6   4    0.6     No
15     32.1  15    2.3     No
16     57.9  12    2.4    Yes
17     30.8  17    1.8     No
18     59.9   7    0.8     No
19     42.7  15    2.0    Yes
20     20.6  18    1.7    Yes
21     62.0   8    1.3     No
22     53.1   7    1.6     No
23     28.9  16    2.2    Yes
24    177.4   5    1.1     No
25     24.8  14    1.5    Yes
26     75.3  14    2.3    Yes
27     51.6   7    1.4     No
28     36.1   9    1.1     No
29    116.1   6    1.1     No
30     28.1  16    2.5    Yes
31      8.7  19    2.2    Yes
32    105.1   6    0.8     No
33     46.0  15    3.0    Yes
34    102.6   7    1.2     No
35     15.8  15    2.2     No
36     60.0   7    1.3     No
37     96.4  13    2.6     No
38     24.2  14    1.7     No
39     14.5  15    2.4     No
40     36.6  14    1.5     No
41     65.7   5    0.6     No
42    116.3   7    1.6     No
43    113.6   8    1.0     No
44     16.7  15    4.3    Yes
45     66.0   7    1.0     No
46     60.7   7    1.0     No
47     90.6   7    0.7     No
48     91.3   7    1.3     No
49     14.4  18    3.1    Yes
50     72.8  14    3.0    Yes
```

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you're just looking for `format`, which has a `data.frame` method.

A small example:

```
mydf <- mydf2 <- data.frame(
  Distance = c(21.4, 13.9, 23.9, 8.7, 241.8, 44.5),
  Age = c(18, 17, 16, 18, 6, 17),
  Height = c(3.3, 3.4, 2.9, 3.6, 0.7, 1.3),
  Coning = c("Y", "Y", "Y", "N", "N", "Y"))

format(mydf, nsmall = 2)
#   Distance   Age Height Coning
# 1    21.40 18.00   3.30      Y
# 2    13.90 17.00   3.40      Y
# 3    23.90 16.00   2.90      Y
# 4     8.70 18.00   3.60      N
# 5   241.80  6.00   0.70      N
# 6    44.50 17.00   1.30      Y
```

As you *should* expect, if the data are integers, they won't be printed as decimals.

```
mydf2$Age <- as.integer(mydf2$Age)
format(mydf2, nsmall = 2)
#   Distance Age Height Coning
# 1    21.40  18   3.30      Y
# 2    13.90  17   3.40      Y
# 3    23.90  16   2.90      Y
# 4     8.70  18   3.60      N
# 5   241.80   6   0.70      N
# 6    44.50  17   1.30      Y
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to `format` is to globally set the option for the number of digits to be displayed:

```
options(digits=2)
```

Will mean that from that point forward all numerics will be printed up to 2 decimal places (The default is 7).

Comment: Not sure that this would do what the OP is looking for. Compare: `options(digits = 3); pi; c(pi, 2.1); c(2, 2.1); options(digits = 7)`.

Comment: Ah, 2.1 doesn't print out as 2.10.